# How do I use Mididriver or some other android lib to chose the instrument and notes?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, midi

I need to play music notes (preferably midi) for many instruments. The only working solution I have found is mididriver:
https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver
But I do not know how to translate the music notes to its format.

When I used a python code to read a midi file I got some notes and chords like

```
G#4 G#2
```

The mididriver demo shows how to play a 'g' like this:

```
sendMidi(0x90, 55, 63);
sendMidi(0x90, 59, 63);
sendMidi(0x90, 62, 63);
```

Are there any librarys I can use to translate the midi notes to this notation?

Answer (score 1):

The function that you don't understand has three parameters, with this meaning:

```
sendMidi(midi status byte, note number, velocity)
```

- midi status byte: is a single byte combining one of the MIDI message types and the channel in a single byte. For instance 0x90 means NOTE ON and Channel 0.
- note number is a number between 0 and 127 representing a single note. For instance, 60 represents the note C4 (middle C).
- velocity is the amount of strength used to trigger the note/key.

All of this is part of the MIDI specification. You only need to download and familiarize with it. Here are some pointers:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI#Messages

https://www.midi.org/specifications

Comment: By the way, I've made a similar project, also based on the SonivoxEAS Android synth. Maybe it can be useful to you.
[NativeGMSynth](https://github.com/pedrolcl/android/blob/master/NativeGMSynth/src/com/example/nativegmsynth/MainActivity.java)